# NullPointerException in CustomListAdapter while setting the adapter from a Fragment

Tags: android

I have a ListView inside a LinearLayout named `listView1`, and for a particular row, I have a LinearLayout inside which there is a `com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureViewer` and a TextView. I have created a `CustomListAdapter` to populate the List.
I am setting the adapter from the `Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync().`

I am posting this after researching in a number of similar post on the stackoverflow as well as other tutorials. Please help, I am stuck on this from last 1 day.

**list_item.xml**

```
<com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/friendProfilePicture"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp" >
</com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_friendName"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:text="Name"/>
```

I think I am either setting the adapter wrong or have something mismatch in the adapter's constructor.

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Context context;
private String[] names;
private String[] ids;

public MyAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, String[] n, String[]i) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, n);
    this.context = context;
    names = n;
    ids = i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    TextView tvName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_friendName);
    ProfilePictureView profilePic = (ProfilePictureView) vi.findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
    tvName.setText(names[position]);
    profilePic.setProfileId(ids[position]);
    return vi;
}
}
```

and here is the code where I am setting the adapter,

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
```

and the statement for setting the adapter

```
context = MainActivity.context;

listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(context,R.layout.list_item, names, id));
```

There is a static variable context of type `Context`in the MainActivty.java,

names and id are two String Arrays which are having values and are not null.

Here is the StackTrace

```
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at azeem.anas.facebookloginbutton.MyAdapter.<init>(MyAdapter.java:19)
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at azeem.anas.facebookloginbutton.MainFragment$3.onCompleted(MainFragment.java:103)
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at com.facebook.Request$2.onCompleted(Request.java:285)
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1240)
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-15 07:02:07.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3367):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: change  `super(context, R.layout.list_item, n);` with  `super(context, android.R.id.text1, n);` and see if it makes any difference

Comment: debug and check if `vi` is null

Comment: @blackbelt : changing it didn't do anything. :-(

Comment: @vilpe89 : I have written a log statement in the getView() method. But stragely, it doesn't run.

Comment: change `context = MainActivity.context;` with `context = getActivity();`

Comment: @blackbelt : thank you but tried that already, now it give the NPE on the 

<code>profilePic.setProfileId(ids[position]);</code>

 of the MyAdapter.java class.

it says 07-15 07:33:42.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4213): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 07:33:42.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4213):  at azeem.anas.facebookloginbutton.MyAdapter.getView(MyAdapter.java:44)

Comment: @vilpe89 : I checked it but vi is not null,its got reference of a LinearLayout

Comment: Profi TVE id of the view is friendProfilePicture and you try to find a view with id profilepic un tour adapter. Anyway tour adapter is not efficient and you should use convertview for imagen recycling as well as viewHolder to keep a referente to row views.I will post an anwer later with muy opinión of how to improve it. By the way, never do a context static, doing you can create memory leaks really easy

Comment: A very **silly mistake** i have done, in the following statement in the Adapter class

<code>ProfilePictureView profilePic = (ProfilePictureView) vi.findViewById(R.id.profilepic);</code>,

I was referring to a wrong resource. It was actually

 <code>ProfilePictureView profilePic = (ProfilePictureView) vi.findViewById(R.id.friendProfilePicture);</code>

****
**Thnaks to all those who made efforts in solving my problem**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very **silly mistake** i have done, in the following statement in the Adapter class

`ProfilePictureView profilePic = (ProfilePictureView) vi.findViewById(R.id.profilepic);`,

I was referring to a wrong resource. It was actually

`ProfilePictureView profilePic = (ProfilePictureView) vi.findViewById(R.id.friendProfilePicture);`

---

**Thanks to all those who made efforts in solving my problem**

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
   private String[] ids;

   public MyAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, String[] n, String[] i) {
       super(context, R.layout.list_item, n);
       this.ids = i;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = convertView;
      if (view == null) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         view = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);
      }
      TextView tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_friendName);
      ProfilePictureView profilePic = (ProfilePictureView) view.findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
      tvName.setText(getItem(position));
      profilePic.setProfileId(ids[position]);
      return view;
   }
}
```

Try this it should Work.
And keep `context = getActivity();`

Important : call `listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(context,R.layout.list_item, names, id));` in `onActivityCreateed()`